# Not able to enter bios from restart

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, reboot

I have an asus Sabertooth 990FX motherboard running BIOS revision 1604. I previously had to RMA it and they sent me a new one. Since then I've haven't been able to get into BIOS on restart, but from a cold boot I can enter the bios with delete as usual. Anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a USB keyboard, and the USB interface is loading too slow to get your keyboard powered on. This can be seen by the numlock going on in time.

The best way to counteract this, is to make sure the keyboard is plugged into a USB port on the rear of the computer, as these ports are initialised first, which increases the chance to get the bios loaded.

Disabling Quick POST might help you increasing the time spending in the bios screen which may delay it enough for the keyboard to get loaded and get you to press DEL in time.

Comment: Yes, and also unplug other devices (as much as possible) such as printers, cameras and so on, to find which devices are creating that problem.

Comment: Wouldn't the keyboard power on faster / not power off during a restart as compared to powering on from cold?

Comment: No. Thats not how USB works. During each boot, the power goes off the system very briefly. USB gives a low powered output through USB which devices such as keyboards utilize. When the system restarts, and the power is lost very briefly, the keyboard is also "reset". For that reason, at power-on, the keyboard gets a "initialise yourself" signal sent, which it uses to power on. Depending on the order of devices plugged in, each device gets powered on one after another. This starts at the back of the pc and moves its way to the front. More in next comment>>

Comment: >> A USB hub will send the signal that it was powered on to the mainhub before starting to initialize its own devices, but this adds a delay to getting all devices on a hub initialized.. Taking this in mind, the optimal thing to do is plug in the keyboard in the very first USB slot, but given that you'd have to open your pc to find out which of all the ports is the first one, and while it usually works in any port, I left that part out.